# Is "uncarefully" a word?

Tags: word-choice, is-it-a-word

Microsoft Word is telling me that is isn't.

If it isn't, what is a suitable alternative?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it isn't. *Carelessly* is the word you are looking for.

Comment: Well — *uncarefully* is a word; but it’s a very rare one, and *carelessly* is almost certainly a better choice.

Comment: I stand corrected. It is a word. Albeit a very seldomly used one.

Comment: If you stand corrected in your comment, shouldn't you either delete the answer, or at least amend the text in it so it says what you now accept?

Answer (score 6):

*Carelessly* is much more common, and, generally, you should use it, but, yes, *uncarefully* is a word. Google Books shows it was used by [Richard Bulstrode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Bulstrode) (died 1711) and has been in use ever since.

Answer (score 4):

For an alternative that, to me, has a slightly different connotation from "carelessly", how about "incautiously"?